# Yii DB Connection Error

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I'm getting the following error from my page at http://ocytoronto.org/demo/.

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1193 Unknown system variable 'NAMES'
```

What's more confusing is this used to work fine till yesterday. Any help?

Main.php added.

```
return array(
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'Office of Catholic Youth, Roman Catholic Archdiocese of Toronto',

// preloading 'log' component
'preload'=>array('log'),

// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),

'modules'=>array(
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'PASSWORD',
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),

),

// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),
    // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                    'showScriptName'=>true,

        'rules'=>array(
            'admin'=>'site/login',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),

    ),

    /*'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
    ),
    */
    // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=sqlc9.megasqlservers.com;dbname=ocy_db',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'USERNAME',
        'password' => 'PASSWORD',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),

    'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),
    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            /*
            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),
            */
        ),
    ),
    'controllerMap'=>array(
            'YiiFeedWidget' => 'ext.yii-feed-widget.YiiFeedWidgetController'
    ),

    'file'=>array(
      'class'=>'application.extensions.file.CFile',
    ),
),

// application-level parameters that can be accessed
// using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
'params'=>array(
    // this is used in contact page
    'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
),
```

);

Any help would me much appreciated.

Comment: What is your mysql version?

Comment: show your config `main.php` script

Comment: @Mihai: The version is 5.1.70.

Comment: what have you changed till yesterday? Unknown system variable says it clear;

Comment: @som: main.php added.

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian: That's the thing. I haven't made any changes to the code for a couple of weeks. I'm worried if the client might have misplaced some files. That is the only possible change i can think of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but you can do that 
Remove :  `'charset' => 'utf8'` from db array

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=sqlc9.megasqlservers.com;dbname=ocy_db',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'USERNAME',
        'password' => 'PASSWORD',
        'charset' => 'utf8', // remove this line and check
    ),
```

Comment: how come? utf8 not compatible? what?

Comment: if this is the issue, this means that you might not be using linux, or the db does not support utf8 ?